# Virtualbox not detecting vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, filesystems, vdi

I recently moved my vms from another drive to main drive and when I tried to add them again instead of the VDI file I am met with nothing. In the actual directory there is the vdi file.
[image]

Comment: Virtualbox does not do any autodetecting. You must go to the virtual media manager, remove the old one, and then add the new one.

Comment: @LPChip well, you don't understand my question..

Comment: @ssss It would help if you edited your question and added some more information. That screenshot shows nothing of interest. We can't guess what you expected to see there. I totally agree with LPChip. Normally NOTHING shows up automatically  in VirtualBox. You will have to re-attach each VDI with the virtual media manager and fix up the config of each VM after  you moved stuff around. In some cases the VirtualBox GUI can get confused enough that you have to manually edit the .vbox files to correct wrong paths.

Comment: If @LPChip doesn't understand your question, I don't either, and that indicates the problem is how you have described your problem, and can be resolved by you using the EDIT button to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

- Select `Add` under `Medium` after you start VirtualBox.
- In the `Please choose a virtual hard disk file` window, find your vdi file and select `Open`. Your vdi file should now listed inside `Hard disks`.
- Select `New` under `Machine`, assign a name (your choice) to your VM. Other options don't really matter but I'd change the OS type and version so that the displayed information and the actual VM are consistent. Otherwise, you will see your VM shows Windows 10 when it is actually an Ubuntu VM.
  -:Click `Next`.
- Select the amount of memory and cpu you want and click `Next` again.
- You should see the `Virtual Hard disk` window now. Select `Use an Existing Virtual Hard Disk File` and make sure your vdi file is showing in the combobox, click `Next` again.
- Now, just click `Finish`.